# How do I install old version of R (3.3.x) with apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, r

I am trying to install an old version of R in ubuntu. Normally, I would just do:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

But this gets me the latest version 3.4.x, which I don't want. I want to the older version. However, when I try:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=3.3.3-1
```

or something like that, it says that it cannot find that version. I also tried running something like this:

```
sudo apt-cache madison r-base
```

to see what versions are available, and only the most recent v 3.4.x is available. How do I install the older version through apt-get?

Comment: had you found solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Rbase 3.3.1 appears to be in archive.ubuntu.com

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r-base/r-base_3.3.1-1build1_all.deb

You will need to be sure the repository archive.ubuntu.com